# UICollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios

I'm trying to scroll to a specific item in a collection view and it seems to happening properly about 90 % of the time. I basically have a collection view whose frame I change via auto layout and then I want my cell be the size of the all of the new frame, so I set a new size. When I put a breakpoint on the scrollToItemAtIndexPath, it seems when it works works the item size have taken effect, but the times it doesn't work, the cell still have the old size. How can I make sure the itemSize has changed before scrolling?

```
[weakSelf.view removeConstraints:@[weakSelf.verticalSpace, weakSelf.collectionViewBottomSpace, weakSelf.bottomLayoutTopCollectionView]];
[weakSelf.view addConstraints:@[weakSelf.collectionViewToTop, weakSelf.imageHeight, weakSelf.youLabelToTop]];
[UIView animateWithDuration:animated ? .5 : 0.0
                                      animations:^{
                                          [weakSelf.view layoutIfNeeded];
                                      }
                                      completion:^(BOOL finished) {
  UICollectionViewFlowLayout * layout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.currentUserCollectionView.collectionViewLayout;

  layout.itemSize = weakSelf.currentUserCollectionView.frame.size;

  [weakSelf.currentUserCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self getSelectedIndex:selectItem] inSection:0]
                                         atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally
                                                 animated:NO];
}];
```

Comment: What is the question? You have just pasted code here.

Comment: Sorry...pressed enter too soon

Comment: No worries, not my down vote btw :)

Comment: When you change the layout constraints on the collection view are you calling `invalidateLayout` on it?

Comment: I call layoutIfNeeded. I updated the code.

Comment: Yup, but once you have called layoutIfNeeded you need to tell the CollectionView that it has changed. Try calling `[layout invalidateLayout];` after you have done `layoutIfNeeded`. then the scroll method should know where the item is. OK, so add it at the front of the animation completion block.

Comment: that didn't help. Reading the documentation it seems like the update only happens on the next layout update cycle. I need to know when the update is finished.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Make sure the collection view has laid out its subviews first along with the resizing of the cell before scrolling. I would suggest moving your scrolling to a place where you're sure all layouts have been completed such as:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = // compute some index path

    [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath
                                atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally
                                        animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: scrollToItemAtIndexPath in viewDidLayoutSubviews method can produce an infinite scrolling as viewDidLayoutSubviews will be called after each scroll

Comment: What should be the inndexPath here?  NSIndexPath *indexPath = .. an example plz.

Comment: @KayCee You just need to keep track of where you want to scroll to. For example NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:itemNumber inSection:0]; where itemNumber is an NSInteger being set somewhere else in your code. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 25):

Another option is to call `layoutIfNeeded` on the `UICollectionView` before you call `scrollToItemAtIndexPath`. That way you won't perform the scroll operation every time the parent view's subviews are laid out.

Comment: Wonderfull solution! Very simple and portable.