# Collection View Segue In Code Swift

Tags: swift

I have a collection view and when I click on a button it should move to the next collection view cell. As you can see in the picture below I have the next button and instead of manually swiping it will go to the next index on its[image] own. I have tried googling but have not found any answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UICollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816184/uicollectionview-scrolltoitematindexpath)

Comment: This is good but it so old the syntax is not correct. Could you send me the same answer but with correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not a segue, a segue mainly switches between view controllers. Like @the4kman mentioned, this has been answered in Objective-C already, but I can convert it into Swift 3 for you.

What you want to do is right click and drag from the next button into the class and make it an action. Make sure it is on touchUpInside. This creates an IBAction function that will be called when the button is pressed down.

```
@IBAction func nextBtn_pressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let index = 1 //this variable has to be the index of the next cell
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: index, section: 0), at: .left, animated: true)
    //you can change .left to whatever style you want

}
```

Comment: This works but if a want it to segue one more time how would I do it?

Comment: Like u want it to move 2 pages at once?